# 90s anime with a kid running away in a sewer with his two-headed dog, Cerberus

Tags: story-identification, anime

When I was a kid in the 90s, I remember bits of pieces of this anime, it might have been an OVA given the quality if I remember right.

The parts I remember are this kid who I assume was the main character, running from something, a monster I think, in the sewers with his dog, a two-headed Doberman I think he called Cerberus.

It aired in America in the mid/late 90s and it was most certainly *not* meant for kids.

That's all I can recall having only seen a bit of it as my dad surfed through the channels at the time. I'm sorry this isn't much to go on, I've been searching for this for years and no luck. Sadly that's all the info I can offer.

Comment: Maybe Demon City Shinjuku? One character had a dog companion but I don't remember if it had two heads or just one.

Comment: It does have a two headed dog but i do not think it was this anime, I could be wrong but i suppose i'll just keep looking. Thank you.

Comment: Actually, it sounds like a pretty safe bet. The OVA is about *kids fighting monsters in the sewers*, and the boy's companion is a 2-headed *doberman*.

Comment: Yeah, to be fair I'm going on fairly old memories here so having looked at it again it seems like it is what I've been looking for. Is this thing worth watching?

Comment: I’m looking for this one too. Saw it when I was sick home from school as a kid and been looking for it off and on since. I’m pretty sure the kids weapon was a stick that he swung like a sword and it breaks or at least cracks in the third act.

Answer (score 1):

This is bound to be *[Demon City Shinjuku](https://myanimelist.net/anime/499/Makai_Toshi_Shinjuku)*.

> Kyoya's father was a great warrior, killed at the hands of the diabolical psychic, Rebi Ra, who has now opened a portal to hell in the city of Shinjuku. It falls to Kyoya to finish what his father started and battle his way through demons, while protecting a young woman from harm. The only problem is that he's not exactly your classic hero type, and his powers are still latent.

The boy with the two-headed dog isn't the main character, but he lives in the sewers of Tokyo with the dog, and at one point they're attacked by a large demonic monster, vaguely resembling [the Scorpion King](https://mummy.fandom.com/wiki/Mathayus). That specific scene occurs about thirty minutes into the film.

Also, this was an OVA intended for a mature audience, and it was released in 1988.